# Taylor series of $f(x)=\frac {e^x-1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am asked to expand $f(x)=\frac {e^x-1}{x}$ centered at 0 using the known Talyor series of functions.
How to simplify the function so that it can be expanded more easily?

Comment: Yes! Do I need to simplify this function? or just expand $e^x$ and sub. to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand $e^x$ and subtract 1, then you get something divisible by $x$. You should find
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

In order to expand this into a Taylor series. Do the following. Convert $e^x$ into it's taylor series which is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Therefore for $e^x$ you have:

$$1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} \ldots$$

If you subtract from it $1$ then you will have:

$$x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} \ldots$$

Now you can divide that by $x$.

$$1 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{6} \ldots$$

Then it is easy to see that the answer is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$